# php multidimensional arrays updating based on keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare, array-intersect

I have two arrays inventoryStock and posStock (point of sale stock) they both use product sku numbers as the key and the value is the quantity on hand I need to somehow update the posStock with the values from $inventoryStock where there keys are matching.

Examples of arrays:

```
inventoryStock{
   abs-0098 => 5,
   abs-0099 => 23,
   abs-0100 => 8,
   abs-0101 => 19
}

posStock{
 abs-0098 => 5,
 abs-0099 => 23,
 abs-0101 => 15
}
```

I need the posStock to be the same as the inventoryStock I cannot just make posStock be inventory stock becasue inventory stock has extra products not listed in the Point of sale.

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: IMO it is not very clear as to what you want the result to be. Maybe you could post an array of what you want the combinedStock to be.

Comment: I agree a resulting array would be helpful, I disagree with those voting to close this question as *'Too Broad'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the array_key_exists() function of PHP.

```
foreach ($inventoryStock as $key => $value) {
      if (array_key_exists($key, $posStock)) {
        $posStock[$key] = $value;
        continue; // Continue Loop
      }
      // Do something if the array key doesn't exist.
    }
```

To expand on why I would do it this way. I now have a logic block to allow me to do something if the array key doesn't exist like add it to the PosStock, or if I want to or change values of other variables to trigger other behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array union](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php).

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

In your case (if I understand the spec correctly):

```
$newPOSStock = $inventoryStock + $posStock;
```

Comment: Just for completion sake, this is exactly opposite of array_merge where keys in the left array are overwritten by keys in the right array(s). Sometimes you want to keep the values on the left and use `+` and sometimes you want to keep the values on right and use array_merge.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks @Jonathan Kuhn.